# Do we need CC1 resistors on USB C, embedded MCU circuit?

Tags: usb-c

Do I need cc1 and cc2 resistors just for charging the battery? My embedded board doesn't need standard data transfer. I have on the board a USB type C connector for PC USB to TTL converter, a baud rate of 115200 of MCU on board. On the previous version of the board, I was using USB micro B for charging. To be compatible I just replaced the connector from USM Micro B to USB type C, the rest of the circuit was not changed.

Comment: Show the circuit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need resistors on the CC pins.

IF you omit them then your device will work fine with an A-C cable, but will not work with a C-C cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply change the connector.

If you do not have the resistors, all the devices and cables that have to detect if and when something is connected or not, they will not be able to detect your device.

Only adapters and cables that forcibly have to give out 5V without detecting if anything is connected or not will work with your device.